# Exceeding Amazon AWS Free Tier

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I recently set up an Amazon Free Tier account to store some databases. However, I was stupid enough to not pay attention to the limit of 750 hours per month and created too many instances. This month I will definitely run over the 750 hours. However, my question is the following.

Once I exceeded the free tier limits in one month, would I fall out of the free tier entirely? Or would I still have the free 750 hours once the next month starts (until the end of one year from the creation of the acc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Hourly Usage in the Free Tier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-limits.html#hourly-limits) documentation, the free tier has a limit of 750 hours per month.

So in your case, you will get 750 hours back on the next month of the billing cycle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was also confirmed by amazon itself as I contacted them.